# Max retries exceeded : Geocode Multiple Addresses and Write to excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, here-api

i am trying to geocode a list of addresses and append it to an excel file using HERE API but i am encountering an error max retries exceeded .

Here is my current code:

```
def geocode(location):
    # api-endpoint 
    URL = "https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json"

    # defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API 
    PARAMS = {'searchtext':location, 'gen':9,'apiKey':"s"} 

    # sending get request and saving the response as response object 
    r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS) 

    if response.status_code == 200:
    # extracting data in json format 
    out = r.json() 

    try:

        area =   out['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']['County'] 
        city =   out['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']['City'] 
        zip  =   out['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']['PostalCode'] 

    except IndexError :

        area = ""
        city = ""
        zip = ""



    return out,area,city,zip
```

Here is my loop :

```
# Loop thru addresses

i = 1
for primary in primary_address:
   i = i + 1
   out,area,city,zip = geocode(primary) 
   sheet.cell(row=i, column=first_empty_col).value = area 
   sheet.cell(row=i, column=first_empty_col + 1).value = city
   sheet.cell(row=i, column=first_empty_col + 2).value = zip

book.save('file.xlsx')
```

How do I do this the most efficient way?

Comment: Can you add your error in the post.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiently Geocoding a larger number of locations, you should take a look at the [Batch Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-batch-geocode.html).

Comment: Hi @leopectus I would need to append the results in an existing excel file . I believe if I do the batch geocoding I would be given a zip file

Comment: I believe that's only the case if you set "outputcompressed" to true. Otherwise it should be a plain text file which you can then parse in your code.